# Controller is loaded before resolve is resolved in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My AngularJS resolve doesn't finish before the controller is loaded.

Background: Say I have a "my profile" page that is requested (user loads website.com/user). I would like to have angular intercept the request and ask for the appropriate data from the server.

The server will reply differently depending on whether the user is logged in/active/etc. I would like angular to get the data from the server before it loads the template, and before it initiates the appropriate controller. So far it does not.

App.js code:

```
.when('/user',
  {
    templateUrl:'/templates/user',
    controller: 'my_profile',
    resolve: {
        some_cute_function_name: function($timeout){
            $timeout(function(){
                console.log('here123');
            },5)
        }
   }
```

Meanwhile, controller code:

```
            console.log('about to update scope');
```

It turns out that the controller is initiated before the resolve is done. I know this because the greater the number of seconds before the $timeout is done, the more likely I am to see this:

```
about to update scope
here123
```

as opposed to the other way around.

Is there any way to ensure that the resolve is resolved before the controller is initiated?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Why cant you call some_cute_function_name from within the controller?

Comment: I can, but I wanted to make sure that the data is retrieved before the view is rendered. The resolve function shown here is a simplified version of an AJAX call I'm performing.

Comment: There is `return` statement missing in some_cute_function

Comment: That's right @Chandermani, I've tried that. But even if I add it (either after '},5)' or after '},5)}' - it still doesn't work =(. Wait, do I have to return something relevant, or should "return 3" work?

Comment: The return would be `return $timeout(....`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your resolver needs to return a promise:

```
  .when('/user',
  {
    templateUrl:'/templates/user',
    controller: 'my_profile',
    resolve: {
        some_cute_function_name: function($timeout){
            return $timeout(function(){
                console.log('here123');
                return { some: 'data' };
            },5);
        }
   }
```

Comment: You don't need to create a new deferred object. $timeout itself returns a promise.

Comment: Updated to just return the $timeout's promise.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS describes [resolve](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider) as:

"An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. **If any of these dependencies are promises**, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated." (emphasis added)

I take it that **unless** any of the dependencies are promises, angular won't wait for resolve to finish before instantiating the controller (even if I have operations that take a long time to finish, like a $timeout).

Solution: you have to make sure the resolve involves a promise.

Comment: Hi Adam, I am also facing the same issue, inside my resolve I am calling a factory function in which I am making an http request and inside .then(function(response){.....) I am performing some actions and returning the desired data, do you know what is wrong here? MY_CODE: resolve: some_cute_function_name: function(factory){ return factory.function(params);}
IN_FACTORY : I am returning the data inside .then of http

Comment: @SohailFaruqui are you sure that the factory function is returning a promise?

Comment: I think I forgot to return promiss